# Updatepage | Why does my image field in db get overwritten with null value when I update?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm new to coding, so sorry if some of my jargon is wrong.

I'm trying to make an update page that will update database values. All other fields update fine, however whenever I attempt to update the database without an image upload, it will replace the current field value with a null value. Any help would be appreciated to remedy this issue. Exact code would be excellent, as I said before I'm new to coding, especially asp.net and C# so some terms are new to me.

Below is my code behind file, I imagine this is the cause of my problem.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Configuration;

public partial class admin_updatenews : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void displayedit_ItemUpdated(object sender, ListViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        info.Text = "Item Updated";

        FileUpload fileupdate = displayedit.EditItem.FindControl("imageupdate") as FileUpload;

        Label recordid = displayedit.EditItem.FindControl("idlabel1") as Label;
        Int32 id = Convert.ToInt32(recordid.Text);

        if (fileupdate.HasFile)
        {
            String fupload = fileupdate.FileName;

            Random r = new Random();
            int rInt = r.Next(0, 10000);

            String imgpath = "../images/" + rInt + fupload;

            fileupdate.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(imgpath));

            String newimage = rInt + fupload;

            string newsconnection = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["newsconnection"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(newsconnection);

            //myConnection.ConnectionString is now set to connectionString.
            myConnection.Open();

            String query = "UPDATE News SET postimage ='" + newimage + "', Image ='" + newimage + "' WHERE id='" + id + "'";

            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);

            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            myConnection.Close();
        }
    }
    protected void displayedit_ItemEditing(object sender, ListViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        info.Text = "I am editing";
    }
    protected void displayedit_ItemCanceling(object sender, ListViewCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        info.Text = "Not Updating";
    }
}
```

This is the front end code in case that is required

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Copy of updatenews.aspx.cs" Inherits="admin_updatenews" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <link href="../css/responsive.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
        <link href="../css/gui.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="newseditrows" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:newsconnection %>' 
            SelectCommand="SELECT News.id, News.headline, News.Image, News.paragraph, Sportslist.sportname, News.Sport,  News.date, News.lead, News.authorID, Sportslist.id, News.postheadline, News.postimage, News.postparagraph, News.postsport, News.postdate, News.postlead, News.postauthorid
                            FROM News 
                            INNER JOIN Sportslist ON News.Sport = Sportslist.id
                            ORDER BY News.id DESC"
            UpdateCommand="UPDATE [News] SET [headline]=@headline, [Image]=@Image, [paragraph]=@paragraph, [Sport]=@sport, [date]=@date, [lead]=@lead, [authorid]=@authorid, [postheadline]=@headline, [postimage]=@Image, [postparagraph]=@paragraph, [postsport]=@sport, [postdate]=@date, [postlead]=@lead, [postauthorid]=@authorid WHERE [id]=@id">

            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="headline" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Image" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="paragraph" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Sport" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="date" Type="DateTime" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="lead" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="authorid" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="Int32" />
            </UpdateParameters>

        </asp:SqlDataSource>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sportlist" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:newsconnection %>' 
            SelectCommand="SELECT [id], [sportname] FROM [Sportslist]">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>

        <asp:Label ID="info" runat="server" Text="Not Updating"></asp:Label>
        <br />

        <asp:ListView ID="displayedit" runat="server" 
            DataSourceID="newseditrows" 
            DataKeyNames="id" 
            OnItemUpdated="displayedit_ItemUpdated" 
            OnItemEditing="displayedit_ItemEditing" 
            OnItemCanceling="displayedit_ItemCanceling">

            <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                <span style="">id:
                    <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("id") %>' runat="server" ID="idLabel" /><br />
                    headline:
                    <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("headline") %>' runat="server" ID="headlineLabel" /><br />
                    Image:
                    <asp:Image ID="ImageLabel" runat="server" ImageURL='<%# "../images/" + Eval("Image") %>' Width="100px" />
                    <br />
                    paragraph:
                    <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("paragraph") %>' runat="server" ID="paragraphLabel" /><br />
                    Sport:
                    <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("sportname") %>' runat="server" ID="SportLabel" /><br />
                    date:
                    <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("date") %>' runat="server" ID="dateLabel" /><br />
                    lead:
                    <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("lead") %>' runat="server" ID="leadLabel" /><br />
                    authorID:
                    <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("authorID") %>' runat="server" ID="authorIDLabel" /><br />
                    <asp:Button runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" ID="EditButton" />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                </span>
            </AlternatingItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                    <span style="">id:
                    <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("id") %>' runat="server" ID="idLabel1" /><br />
                    headline:
                    <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("headline") %>' runat="server" ID="headlineTextBox" /><br />
                    Image:
                    <asp:Image ID="ImageTextBox1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "../images/" + Eval("Image") %>' Width="100px"/>
                    <asp:FileUpload ID="imageupdate" runat="server" />
                    <br />
                    paragraph:
                    <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("paragraph") %>' runat="server" ID="paragraphTextBox" /><br />
                    Sport:
                    <%--<asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("Sport") %>' runat="server" ID="SportTextBox" />--%>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="SportsDropdown" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Sport") %>'>

                        <asp:ListItem Value="1">Football</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="2">Rugby</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="3">Basketball</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="4">Motorsport</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="5">NFL</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="6">Cricket</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="7">Tennis</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="8">Golf</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="9">Other</asp:ListItem>

                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <br />
                    lead:
                    <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("lead") %>' runat="server" ID="leadTextBox" /><br />
                    <asp:Button runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" ID="UpdateButton" /><asp:Button runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" ID="CancelButton" /><br />
                    <br />
                </span>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                <span>No data was returned.</span>
            </EmptyDataTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <span style="">headline:
                    <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("headline") %>' runat="server" ID="headlineTextBox" /><br />
                    Image:
                    <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("Image") %>' runat="server" ID="ImageTextBox" /><br />
                    paragraph:
                    <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("paragraph") %>' runat="server" ID="paragraphTextBox" /><br />
                    Sport:
                    <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("Sport") %>' runat="server" ID="SportTextBox" /><br />
                    date:
                    <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("date") %>' runat="server" ID="dateTextBox" /><br />
                    lead:
                    <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("lead") %>' runat="server" ID="leadTextBox" /><br />
                    authorID:
                    <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("authorID") %>' runat="server" ID="authorIDTextBox" /><br />
                    <asp:Button runat="server" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" ID="InsertButton" /><asp:Button runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Clear" ID="CancelButton" /><br />
                    <br />
                </span>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <span style="">id:
                    <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("id") %>' runat="server" ID="idLabel" /><br />
                    headline:
                    <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("headline") %>' runat="server" ID="headlineLabel" /><br />
                    Image:
                    <asp:Image ID="ImageLabel" runat="server" ImageURL='<%# "../images/" + Eval("Image") %>' Width="100px" />
                    <br />
                    paragraph:
                    <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("paragraph") %>' runat="server" ID="paragraphLabel" /><br />
                    Sport:
                    <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("sportname") %>' runat="server" ID="SportLabel" /><br />
                    date:
                    <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("date") %>' runat="server" ID="dateLabel" /><br />
                    lead:
                    <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("lead") %>' runat="server" ID="leadLabel" /><br />
                    authorID:
                    <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("authorID") %>' runat="server" ID="authorIDLabel" /><br />
                    <asp:Button runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" ID="EditButton" />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                </span>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <div runat="server" id="itemPlaceholderContainer" style=""><span runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" /></div>
                <div style="">
                    <asp:DataPager runat="server" ID="DataPager1">
                        <Fields>
                            <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button" ShowFirstPageButton="True" ShowNextPageButton="False" ShowPreviousPageButton="False"></asp:NextPreviousPagerField>
                            <asp:NumericPagerField></asp:NumericPagerField>
                            <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button" ShowLastPageButton="True" ShowNextPageButton="False" ShowPreviousPageButton="False"></asp:NextPreviousPagerField>
                        </Fields>
                    </asp:DataPager>

                </div>
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <SelectedItemTemplate>
                <span style="">id:
                    <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("id") %>' runat="server" ID="idLabel" /><br />
                    headline:
                    <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("headline") %>' runat="server" ID="headlineLabel" /><br />
                    Image:
                    <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Image") %>' runat="server" ID="ImageLabel" /><br />
                    paragraph:
                    <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("paragraph") %>' runat="server" ID="paragraphLabel" /><br />
                    Sport:
                    <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Sport") %>' runat="server" ID="SportLabel" /><br />
                    date:
                    <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("date") %>' runat="server" ID="dateLabel" /><br />
                    lead:
                    <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("lead") %>' runat="server" ID="leadLabel" /><br />
                    authorID:
                    <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("authorID") %>' runat="server" ID="authorIDLabel" /><br />
                    <asp:Button runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" ID="EditButton" />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                </span>
            </SelectedItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can do it two ways.. check the file uploaded.. if not uploaded than dont update that field. or in database use ISNULL(newfield, oldfield). EDIT>> sorry i may have miss understood your question. "whenever I attempt to update the database without an image upload, it will replace the current field value with a null value." is that mean only one field.. or all of the fields?

Comment: @AJP Just the image field. Every other field is fine.

Comment: @AJP Here is a series of images to highlight my problem

Inserted data
http://gyazo.com/73526080a7ed957bfb672380c5d4f591

Inserted Data displayed
http://gyazo.com/ef235f244835cf7904dccbd1dc0ba61a

Edit Inserted Data
http://gyazo.com/1bf20be89396ce3e99c642f9ec76d0e5

Update Inserted Data
http://gyazo.com/1917265a58d6037739b2a2943c3a6842

Updated Database
http://gyazo.com/d99cddcbac5ee3b57784370af70ad880

Comment: Try ISNULL in your update statement. it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is example of the update statement using ur query.

```
UPDATE News 
    SET postimage = ISNULL(YourNewValue, postimage), Image = ISNULL(YourNewValue, Image) 
WHERE id = YourID
```

EDIT :

try adding following in your datasource updateCommand. if this doesn't solve than try stepping through to see where this is adding null.

```
UpdateCommand="UPDATE [News] SET [headline]=@headline, [Image]= ISNULL(@Image, [Image]), [paragraph]=@paragraph, [Sport]=@sport, [date]=@date, [lead]=@lead, [authorid]=@authorid, [postheadline]=@headline, [postimage]=@Image, [postparagraph]=@paragraph, [postsport]=@sport, [postdate]=@date, [postlead]=@lead, [postauthorid]=@authorid WHERE [id]=@id">
```

Comment: Sorry, as I mentioned, I'm completely new to coding so this is kind of over my head a little. I tried this and it's still removing the data from database. `String query = "UPDATE News SET postimage = ISNULL('" + newimage + "', postimage), Image = ISNULL('" + newimage + "', Image) WHERE id='" + id + "'";`